# How to get AdMod to show actual ads instead of test ads and how does it work?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, admob

I had submitted my app to app store recently and got rejected due to `2.9 - Apps that are "demo", "trial", or "test" versions will be rejected. Beta Apps may only be submitted through TestFlight and must follow the TestFlight guidelines`. It was because I had implemented `AdMob` banner on the bottom of the screen and it showed test ads saying that "You are displaying 728x90 test ad from AdMob". In next steps by Apple it says `Please remove all references to “demo,” “trial,” “beta,” or “test” in your application description, app icon, screenshots, previews, release notes, and binary`. I was thinking maybe after apple accepts my app, I will be able to link it to `app.admob.com`, but then I can't my app on the website since its not on the app store yet. What do I need to do with `AdMod` to get it to show actual ads?

Answer (score 0):

there is a testing mode flag that you either set to true or false..
in order to help you further, what are you using, xcode unity corona or what ?

Comment: could you also please explain how AdMob would work? Do I just link my app to the website after it gets put on app store or I can do that beforehand?

Comment: so i have looking around and went through my `AdMob` code and realized that I have `banner.adUnitID = "ca-...."`, so i changed that to the id that I get from AdMob website when I create a new app, but then it doesn't show an Ad on the iphone.

Comment: if you had 
banner.adUnitID = "ca-...."
then you need to read the documentation before asking, read it and come back with any question if you are stuck, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should check and make sure your app id is not a test id, and that it is really your id given to you from admob

Answer (score 0):

If you have created an ad in Admob, it should give you an ad id. Make sure that the id that is in you code is that id, and not a test id.

Also, when you do this, make sure you set your ads test devices equal to whatever devices YOU will test it on.

A simple YouTube search can find you an abundant of videos. Maybe follow this video

[Geeky Lemon](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xavAfvWrClk)